# Is sustained use discount calculated across projects?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

[[Diagram] SUD across projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWnMv.png)

Please take a look on the diagram above.

I need to know, will be VM1 and VM2  considered as single inferred instance or not.

For example, VM1 runned 25% of the month, machine VM2 also 25% and they are not overlapped at the timeline, but they are in different projects.

Will they be treated as single inferred instance with 50% usage of the month or due to the fact that they are in different projects this will not happen?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a billing question and not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Comment: The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/sustained-use-discounts#inferred_inst) does not specified whether or not the VMs need to live in the same project. I believe if both projects are under the same billing account the discount would apply. I agree this is a billing question and I would suggest to reach out [Google Cloud Platform Billing Support team](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing) for any query/clarification.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, VM1 runned 25% of the month, machine VM2 also 25% and
>   they are not overlapped at the timeline, but they are in different
>   projects.
>
> Will they be treated as single inferred instance with 50% usage of the
>   month or due to the fact that they are in different projects this will
>   not happen?

The instances are evaluated within a project and within a region and not collectively across projects or across regions. In your example, if they were in the same project and the same region then 50% usage discounts would apply (25% + 25%). Discounts begin at 25% sustained usage each month.

VM instance usage is combined within a region. Two instances running 50% of the month are equivalent to 100% of one instance for discount purposes. Note that larger instance sizes is broken down to CPU equivalents.

To quote Google:

*Sustained use discounts are applied automatically to usage within a project separately for each region, so there is no action required on your part to enable these discounts.*

Source: [Google: Sustained Use Discounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/sustained-use-discounts)